# Display AVIF images?

Tags: images, linux, image-mode, image-dired, emacs28

I enabled `image-use-external-converter`, and I added `avif` to `image-file-name-extensions` and `AVIF` to `imagemagick-enabled-types`. However, that doesn't do the trick.

I would like AVIF files to render in a buffer as well as in `image-dired`.

Comment: you need imagemagick >= 7.0.25